# Question about homogeneous differential equation and invariance under a similarity transformation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, conic-sections, homogeneous-equation

This regards Apostol Calculus 1 exercise 14 of section 13.25 .

In the exercise it is required to use the Cartesian equation of all conics of eccentricity $e$ and center at the origin to prove that these conics are integral curves of the differential equation $$y' = (e^2-1)\frac{x}{y}$$
This is easy enough because differentiating $\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2(1-e^2)}=1$  gives $x(1-e^2)+yy' = 0$ which implies the given d.e.

But then there is a note which says :

> Since this is a homogeneous differential equation ($y' = f(x,y) = f(tx,ty)$) the set of all such conics of eccentricity $e$ is invariant under a similarity transformation

I don't get why this is true, I understand that it is a homogeneous d.e. but I don't get the relation with invariance under a similarity transformation (replacing $x$ with $tx$ and $y$ with $ty$ in the *equation of the ellipse*).

Can someone clarify please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Not the single ellipse is invariant, but the set of all solution, of all ellipses with the given eccentricity.

Comment: Replacing $x$ with $tx$ and $y$ with $ty$ in the equation of the ellipse gives a different ellipse, but with the same eccentricity.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann ok but I can't see the same the relationship with the homogeneous d.e., can you explain further if possible please? maybe it's trivial but I don't get it anyway

Comment: There are two "homogeneous" in differential equations. One is the homogeneous version of a linear DE, with zero on the right side, the other is where $y'$ is a function of $y/x$ like here.

Comment: I'm still lost :P , how do I apply the transformation to the set in question which I think is $\{y=f(x) \: | \: y' = (e^2-1)\frac{x}{y}\}$ and conclude that since the condition is a homogeneous d.e. then we have done?

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca I know that, but I don't see the connection with the d.e., which is it?

Comment: I'm sure enough that the set I mentioned contained all and only ellipses with eccentricity $e$, and I agree that replacing $x$ with $tx$ and $y$ with $ty$ in the equation of any ellipse in the set gives another ellipse in the set, still I don't get the link with homog.d.e.

Comment: The d.e. is invariant under that transformation, hence the set of its solutions must be invariant too.

Comment: Ok, I get this, so it is just this what the author was saying ? I was getting crazy, then I was seeing more than what was actually written, thank you very much